# How to see ReadFile results with ProcMon

Tags: executable, winapi, api, hooking

I running `procmon` to monitor my process,  and see that my process uses `ReadFile` API.

How can I see which data the process received when it uses `ReadFile`?

Answer (score 3):

TLDR; you can't.

ProcMon does not record the **data** which has been read, it only records the API call arguments and return value (such as success or error code). If you want to see the data as well, a debugger or another tool like [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) may be more suitable.